# Connection, torsion and curvature in index notation

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold with a linear connection $\nabla$ and $X,Y,Z$ vector fields.

The **torsion** is a $(1,2)$ tensor field $\tau = \tau^{i}_{jk} \partial_i \otimes dx^j\otimes dx^k $ such that 
$$ \tau(X,Y)=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y] $$
which is still a vector field. Given a chart the coordinates are obtained by letting $\tau$ act on two elementary vector fields:
$$\tau(\partial_h,\partial_k)=\tau^j_{hk}\partial_i=\nabla_h\partial_k-\nabla_k\partial_h-[\partial_h,\partial_k]=(\Gamma_{hk}^i-\Gamma_{kh}^i)\partial_i$$
$$\tau_{hk}^i = \Gamma_{hk}^i-\Gamma_{kh}^i $$
This means that the connection is torsion-free iff the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in the two lower indeces.

The **curvature** is a $(1,3)$ tensor field $R=R^i_{jhk}\partial_i \otimes dx^j \otimes dx^h \otimes dx^k$ such that

$$R(X,Y,Z) = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z -\nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
which, again, is still a vector field. The coordinates in a chart are again obtained by letting $R$ act on three elementary vector fields:
$$R(\partial_j,\partial_h,\partial_k) = R^i_{jhk} \partial_i = \nabla_j \nabla_h \partial_k - \nabla_h \nabla_j \partial_k -0 $$
Straightforward "Leibniz" rule leads to
$$  R^i_{jhk} = \partial_j \Gamma_{hk}^i - \partial_h\Gamma_jk^i+\Gamma_{hk}^r\Gamma_{jr}^i-\Gamma_{jk}^r\Gamma_{hr}^i \quad \quad (1) $$
This relation is **general** and does makes use of the symmetry of the Ch. symbols. Then,

$$ [\nabla_j, \nabla_h]X \equiv R(\partial_j, \partial_h, X) = R^i_{jhr}X^r \partial_i $$

But the correct formula for a connection **with torsion** has an additional term, as said  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174208/curvature-tensor-for-a-manifold-with-torsion). How does this term arise?

Comment: It seems you messed up something here. Your formula(in fact, definition) of the curvature tensor holds for connections with nonvanishing torsion, and people sometimes prefer using notation like $\nable^2_{X,Y}=\nabla_X\nabla_Y-\nabla_{\nabla_XY}$. In that case the difference betwen $\nabla_{\nabla_XY}$ and $\nabla_{XY}$ must be measured by the torsion part, which is why there's an additional term involving torsions when you rewrite the curvature tensor in $\nabla^2$.

Comment: Cab you please be a bit more explicit? I still don't see how the extra term arises. From the abstract definition of curvature the last expression I wrote seemingly follows immediately, I don't see where symmetry of $\Gamma$ should play a role.

Comment: Ah, you may be confused by misinterpreting the notation like $\nabla_j\nabla_kX^r$. To make the torsion tensor involved, $\nabla_j\nabla_kX^r$ must be the $r$-th component of $\nabla^2_{\partial_j\partial_k}X$, not that of  $\nabla_{\partial_j}\nabla_{\partial_k}X$. This interpretation is justified essentially because what you are trying is to compute the covariant derivative of $\nabla X$ as $(1,1)$-tensor, not that of $\nabla_{\partial_k}X$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking $\nabla_j \nabla_k X^r$ as the $r$-th component of  $\nabla_j \nabla_k X$. Thanks! I'll try to work out the calculation with this new idea, but then where is the$\nabla^2_{X,Y}$ from?

Comment: All right, now the components of the torsion immediately pop out. Thanks!! The question is then now conceptual: why would one be interested in computing  $\nabla_X \nabla_Y -\nabla_{\nabla_XY}$ rather then $\nabla_X \nabla_Y$?

Comment: Because $\nabla_X\nabla_Y-\nabla_{\nabla_XY}=\nabla^2_{X,Y}$. Taking second covariant derivatives is as natural as taking curvature tensor, so it's in a sense just a matter of taste.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to reverse engineer the problem. For a $(1,1)$ tensor $t=t^i_j \partial_i dx^j$ one can prove that $(\nabla_i t )^h_k=\partial_i t^h_k+\Gamma_{ia}^ht^a_k-\Gamma^b_{ik}t^h_b$. This is the $(h,k)$ component of the $(1,1)$ form $\nabla_it$. Formally putting $t^\alpha_\nu=\nabla_\nu X^\alpha$, "forgetting about the meaning of the objects and applying the formula to $\nabla_\mu t^\alpha_\nu$" leads to the correct result (this is how my colleagues solved it).

Comment: But if this works it means that what we're actually doing is computing the $(\alpha, \nu)$ component of the $(1,1)$ tensor $\nabla_\mu(\nabla X)$, as you suggested in a comment. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. And I think that's why second covariant derivatives appears more often in old literatures, especially when written in physicist's notation.

Comment: Ok. For the records, $(\nabla X)^i_j=(\nabla_jX)^i$, from the definition of total covariant derivative. So the notation (which I start to consider a very sad notation) $"\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu X^\alpha"$ stands for $\left(\nabla_\mu (\nabla X)\right)_\nu^\alpha$.  But you also said that $"\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu X^\alpha" = \left( \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu X - \nabla_{\nabla_\mu \partial_\nu}X \right)^\alpha$. Some computation shows that these two quantities actually are the same. Great! Now I just have to understand the meaning behind the computation.

Comment: Sorry if I insist on the matter but this was briefly introduced in my GR course with little care for the math, and I find going from index to abstract far harder (and less clever) than the opposite.