# Reconciling different expressions for Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

[Note: This has been crossposted to Physics SE, but I haven't found a thourough explanation there so far, so I'm posted the question here as well] *I'm using Einstein's summation convention throughout. Also since I'm new to this subject, I'd be really grateful if any assertions can be shown through explicit calculations so that I can follow along and learn in the process.*

I'm reading [Carroll's GR notes](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll3.html) and I'm having trouble deciphering a particular expression for the Riemann curvature tensor. The coordinate-free definition is (eq. 3.71 in Carroll's notes):
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z\tag{3.71}$$
Some more background on the first equation, based on my reading of "Semi-Riemannian Geometry: The Mathematical Language of General Relativity" by Newman:

$R$ is a map from $\mathfrak{X}(M)^3$ to $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that (3.71) holds. Newman's book doesn't really treat $R(X,Y)$ as a separate object (as far as I've read). $R$ is just treated as a map of 3 vector fields and with the weird notation $R(X,Y)Z$ instead of $R(X,Y,Z)$ (again, as far as I've read). Then there is a theorem showing that $R$ is multilinear in all its arguments and anti-symmetric in its first 2 arguments. And then the following assertion:

> Let $(M,\nabla)$ be a smooth manifold with a connection, and let $(U,(x^i))$ be a chart on $M$. Then in local coordinates, $R(\partial/\partial x^{\mu},\partial/\partial x^{\nu})\partial/\partial x^{\sigma}$ can be expressed as: $$R\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}}=R_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}^{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\rho}}$$

Based on the above, if $V\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, then
$$R\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)V=R\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)\bigg(V^{\sigma}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}}\bigg)
\\=V^{\sigma}R\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}}=V^{\sigma}R_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}^{\eta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\eta}}$$
where the second equality holds due to multilinearity of $R$.
Now if I act this on the $x^{\rho}$ coordinate function, I get
$$\bigg(R\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)V\bigg)(x^{\rho})\equiv\bigg(R\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\bigg)V\bigg)^{\rho}=V^{\sigma}R_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}^{\eta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\eta}}(x^{\rho})
\\=V^{\sigma}R_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}^{\eta}\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\eta}}=R_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}^{\rho}V^{\sigma}\tag{1}$$

So far, so good. **Important note: I'm using the notation $\nabla_{\mu}\equiv\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}}$, where $\partial/\partial x^{\mu}$ is the $\mu$-th basis vector field on $(U,(x^i))$**.

Now in eq. (3.71), I can replace $X,Y$ by fields $\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}$ respectively and $Z$ by $V$, then I can get the local coordinates for both sides by acting them on coordinate function $x^{\rho}$:
$$(R(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})V)(x^{\rho})\equiv(R(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})V)^{\rho}=([\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V)(x^{\rho})-(\nabla_{[\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}]}V)(x^{\rho})
\\=([\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V)(x^{\rho})\equiv([\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V)^{\rho}\tag{2}$$

Comparing (1) and (2), I get $$R_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}^{\rho}V^{\sigma}=([\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V)^{\rho}\tag{3}$$

The above equation completely follows from (3.71). Now in Carroll's notes, an index-based expression for the Riemann curvature tensor is also given (eq. 3.66):
$$R^{\rho}_{\ \ \sigma\mu\nu}V^{\sigma}=[\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V^{\rho}+T_{\mu\nu}^{\ \ \ \ \lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}V^{\rho}\tag{3.66}$$

*So far torsion-free assumption hasn't been made anywhere*. To reconcile (3.71) with (3.66), I have to show (comparing RHS of (3) and (3.66)):
$$([\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V)^{\rho}=[\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V^{\rho}+T_{\mu\nu}^{\ \ \ \ \lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}V^{\rho}\tag{4}$$

This is where I'm stuck and I really cannot wrap my head around it. How do I go about proving eq. (4)? The first term on the RHS - I can only infer that it's $[\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\mu}](V^{\rho})$. If it were $([\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]V)^{\rho}$, then it would equal the LHS and the 2nd RHS term would just be zero and meaningless to include - this can't be. But then if it's $[\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\mu}](V^{\rho})$, well $V^{\rho}$ is a $C^{\infty}(U)$ function and this would evaluate to $\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}V^{\rho}-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}V^{\rho}=0$ by equality of mixed partial derivatives.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong in the specific approach outlined in this question. I'd appreciate any help or corrections!

---

**EDIT**: Some calculations I've done after looking at the accepted answer:
$$A=\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)=\nabla_X(\nabla_{Y^b\partial_b}Z)=\nabla_X(Y^b\nabla_{\partial_b}Z)$$
$$=X(Y^b)\nabla_{\partial_b}Z+Y^b\nabla_X(\nabla_{\partial_b}Z)=X(Y^b)\nabla_{\partial_b}Z+Y^b\nabla_{X^a\partial_a}(\nabla_{\partial_b}Z)$$
$$=X(Y^b)\nabla_{\partial_b}Z+Y^bX^a\nabla_{\partial_a}(\nabla_{\partial_b}Z)$$
$$\\$$
$$B=\nabla_{\nabla_XY}Z=\nabla_{\nabla_X(Y^b\partial_b)}Z=\nabla_{X(Y^b)\partial_b+Y^b\nabla_X\partial_b}Z$$
$$=\nabla_{X(Y^b)\partial_b}Z+\nabla_{Y^b\nabla_X\partial_b}Z=X(Y_b)\nabla_{\partial_b}Z+Y^b\nabla_{\nabla_X\partial_b}Z$$
$$=X(Y_b)\nabla_{\partial_b}Z+Y^bX^a\nabla_{\nabla_{\partial_a}\partial_b}Z$$
$$\\$$
$$A-B=X^aY^b\nabla_a\nabla_bZ
\\\implies \nabla_{\partial_a}(\nabla_{\partial_b}Z)-\nabla_{\nabla_{\partial_a}\partial_b}Z=\nabla_a\nabla_bZ\tag{5}$$
So now I have to convince myself that eq. (5) is correct.

Comment: Phys.SE crosspost link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/749527/reconciling-different-expressions-for-riemann-curvature-tensor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See also the questions https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342268 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174322/261022.

The problem in your computation is mostly notational: the usual convention distinguishes between $\nabla_X\nabla_YZ$ and $X^aY^b\nabla_a\nabla_bZ$, so that it is in fact *not the standard notation* to let $\nabla_{\partial_a}\nabla_{\partial_b}Z=\nabla_a\nabla_bZ$. Rather, the correct expression also differentiates $\partial_b$ along $\partial_a$, namely $$\nabla_{\partial_a}\nabla_{\partial_b}Z=\nabla_a\nabla_bZ+\nabla_{(\nabla_{\partial_a}\partial_b)}Z.$$ Using this formula in your calculation should give you the expression you are looking for.

To see why the above expression should be the right one, consider the following computation: $$\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)=X^a\nabla_a(Y^b\nabla_bZ)=X^a(\nabla_aY^b)\nabla_bZ+X^aY^b\nabla_a\nabla_bZ=\nabla_{\nabla_XY}Z+X^aY^b\nabla_a\nabla_bZ$$
so that $\nabla\nabla Z(X,Y)=\nabla\left(\nabla Z(Y)\right)(X)-\nabla Z(\nabla_XY)$, for every vector fields $X,Y,Z$. The linked questions/answers provide also some more details, but it boils down to this.

---

Addendum: the covariant derivative $\nabla$ is a connection on the vector bundle $TM\to M$. This means that for any section $Z$ of $TM$ (i.e. a vector field) and any tangent vetor $v$ to $M$, the expression $\nabla_vZ$ is another section of $TM$. So, if $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields, it makes sense to consider $\nabla_X\left(\nabla_Y Z\right)$, but notice that this is not tensorial in $X,Y$. This would cause some problems if we defined $\nabla_a$ to be $\nabla_{\partial_a}$: not for the derivative of a single vector field, but when you iterate the covariant derivative things get more confusing, as we saw.

Anyway, a notation like $\nabla_a\nabla_b T^c$ usually denotes the components of the tensor $\nabla\nabla T$, namely we define $\nabla_a\nabla_b T^c$ to be the unique locally defined function such that $$\nabla\nabla T=\nabla_a\nabla_b T^c\mathrm{d}x^a\otimes\mathrm{d}x^b\otimes\partial_{x^c}$$
so $\nabla_a\nabla_b T^c\mathrm{d}x^a\otimes\mathrm{d}x^b\otimes\partial_{x^c}=\mathrm{d}x^c\left(\nabla\nabla T(\partial_{x^a},\partial_{x^b})\right)$.

Similarly, $\nabla_XY=X^a\nabla_aY^b\partial_{x^b}$, but $\nabla_a Y^b$ is not the derivative of the function $Y^b$. Rather, $\nabla_aY^b=\mathrm{d}x^b(\nabla Y(\partial_{x^a}))$.

Comment: Thank you! A couple of doubts if you don't mind, I'll ask them step by step - first thing is that the equality $\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)=X^a\nabla_a(Y^b\nabla_bZ)$ suggests to me that in general, $\nabla_XV=X^a\nabla_aV$. But I can also write $X=X^a\partial_a$, so $\nabla_XV=\nabla_{X^a\partial_a}V=X^a\nabla_{\partial_a}V$, from which I'm getting the idea that $\nabla_a$ is the same as $\nabla_{\partial_a}$. Is this fine or have I gone wrong in the above logic? And I'm guessing that even if $\nabla_a=\nabla_{\partial_a}$, I can't blindly replace $\nabla_{\partial_a}$ by $\nabla_a$ ... [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd]... since this causes a problem when we're taking successive covariant derivatives. So then the question becomes - if I can interpret $\nabla_{\partial_a}\nabla_{\partial_b}$ as "the composition of covariant derivative w.r.t. $\partial_b$ followed by cov derivative w.r.t. $\partial_a$". Then what should I interpret $\nabla_a\nabla_b$ as?

Comment: I think the answer will be too long for a comment, I will expand my previous answer to include the details

Comment: Sure thing. In that case there's one more thing to clarify - you've equated $X^a(\nabla_aY^b)\nabla_b$ to $\nabla_{\nabla_XY}$. I was trying to figure that out - $X^a(\nabla_aY^b)\nabla_b=(X^a\nabla_aY^b)\nabla_b=(\nabla_XY^b)\nabla_b$. Whereas $\nabla_{\nabla_XY}=(\nabla_XY)^b\nabla_b$. This $(\nabla_XY^b)\nabla_b$ vs. $(\nabla_XY)^b\nabla_b$ difference is confusing - probably yet again I'm missing some notational subtlety.

Comment: I find the notation $\nabla_X\nabla_YZ$ to be confusing. So now I write either $\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)$ or $$\nabla^2_{XY}Z = \nabla_X(\nabla_YZ) - \nabla_{\nabla_XY}Z.$$ The Riemann curvature tensor is $$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla^2_{XY}Z - \nabla^2_{YX}Z. $$

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon: I edited my question to include some calculation I did after looking at your answer. There's a slight difference from your first equation. I had a look at your edits too - my guess is when you're talking about $\nabla\nabla T$, you take $\nabla$ to mean the **total covariant derivative**? In the book I'm reading, the standard covariant derivative $\nabla_X$ is a $\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$ map, whereas the total covariant derivative (confusingly represented by the same symbol nabla) maps $(r,s)$ tensor fields to $(r,s+1)$ tensor fields ... [cont'd]

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon : [cont'd] Another takeaway from your answer is that if $Z$ is a vector field, then $\nabla\nabla Z\equiv\tilde Z$ is a $(1,2)$-tensor field whose components $\tilde Z_{\ \ \ ab}^c$, **by notation convention are denoted as** $\nabla_a\nabla_b X^c$. Is my understanding so far correct? If so, my final doubt is: you've nicely explained what $\nabla_a\nabla_bZ^c$ is. What is $\nabla_a\nabla_bZ$ supposed to be? In case it denotes components of some $(1,0)$-tensor $Z'$, is it supposed to be defined as $Z'(\omega)=\nabla\nabla Z(\omega,\partial_a,\partial_b)$?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari yes, it is the total covariant derivative and yes, $\nabla\nabla Z$ is taking two vectors and giving you a third vector. As for $\nabla_a\nabla_b Z$, it was actually just shorthand for $\left(\nabla_a\nabla_b Z^c\right)\partial_{x^c}$, i.e. $\nabla\nabla Z(\partial_a,\partial_b)$. Does this make sense? I can edit the answer if you prefer.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon: An edit to the answer would be really appreciated, whenever you get time (also note the discrepancy between the first equation in your answer and the last equation (5) in my (now edited) question

Comment: @ShirishKulhari yes of course there is a sign mistake in my answer! Sorry about that, your computation is correct :') I will fix it

Comment: @Deane: What exactly is this $\nabla^2_{XY}Z$ object? e.g. $\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)$ is the the composition of covariant derivatives $\nabla_Y$ followed by $\nabla_X$ applied to $Z$. How do we verbally describe $\nabla^2_{XY}Z$?

Comment: Given a $(1,1)$-tensor $T$, its covariant derivative $\nabla T$ is a $(1,2)$-tensor, where $$\nabla_Y(T(X)) = (\nabla T)(Y,X) + T(\nabla_YX).$$ Fix  a vector field $Z$. Then $T=\nabla Z$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor, and $\nabla^2Z$ denotes the tensor $\nabla T$.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon: Based on your answer and comments' discussion, I've done some calculations to be able to derive the index-based expression of Riemann curvature tensor. When you get the time, could you please check it out and confirm if it seems okay? Link here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/751276/notational-meaning-of-nabla-lambdav-rho-and-nabla-mu-nabla-nuv